# Easier way to edit a numeric array?

Tags: php, arrays, numeric

I took on the daunting task of storing values into a huge numeric array.

The array looks something like this:

```
//April 5
$home_team[1] = "Giants";
$home_team[2] = "Raiders";

$away_team[1] = "Saints";
$away_team[2] = "Titans";

//April 6
$home_team[3] = "Warriors";

$away_team[3] = "Bears";
```

All the way up until the numeric arrays contained 1929 values. But, I messed up and made duplicated numeric arrays in the middle of my code. It looks something like this:

```
//August 11
$home_team[1033] = "Angels";

$away_team[1033] = "Bears";

//August 12
$home_team[1033] = "Titans";

$away_team[1033] = "Bulls";
```

Rather than go back and manually change the values in the numeric array from August 12 and ahead to a number that is one greater than the one that it currently, is there a way that I could do this with php and mysql?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, which I do not understand, you are doing it horribly wrong. To solve the immediate issue, you can just do $home_team[] = 'value'; and it will add the value at the next available slot so you don't have to manually give it an index. So if you always put in a home and an away team they should stay in sync.

Comment: So, you want code to fix your typo?

Comment: If you've hard-coded the values, there is nothing you can do except fix your code. I don't understand how you think MySQL could help, since you don't mention using it anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to specify numbers at all. Just do:

```
$home_team[] = "Giants";
$home_team[] = "Raiders";

$away_team[] = "Saints";
$away_team[] = "Titans";
```

PHP will automatically assign the next index to that element. If you want it to be one-based, you could do:

```
$i = 1;
$j = 1;

$home_team[$i++] = "Giants";
$home_team[$i++] = "Raiders";

$away_team[$j++] = "Saints";
$away_team[$j++] = "Titans";
```

If you wish to "fix" your current code *with* code, you can just iterate over your current array:

```
foreach ($home_team as $team) {
    echo '$home_team[$i++] = "' . $team . "\";\n";
}
```

This will output code:

```
$home_team[$i++] = "Giants";
$home_team[$i++] = "Raiders";
```

which you can then copy and paste into your editor and fill in the missing teams (Angles/Bears).

A better array structure may be:

```
$games = array();

$games[] = array('home'=>'Giants',  'away'=>'Saints');
$games[] = array('home'=>'Raiders', 'away'=>'Titans');
```

That way you don't have to worry about matching indexes between two discrete arrays. Of course, the *best* thing to do is throw this all in a database with tables called `teams`, `games`.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the array keys dont mean anything you can remove them altogether and it will create an index for you automaticlly

```
$home_team[] = "Giants";
$home_team[] = "Raiders";

$away_team[] = "Saints";
$away_team[] = "Titans";
```

There will also need to be the same number of entries in $home_team and $away_team to make sure they match up!

---

As far as using SQL to fix it, you would need to enter all your teams into the database somehow and from that point on it would be **a lot** easier to manage. Probably worth it as it sounds like you don't mind doing lots of data input. Or create a batch SQL script with find and replace or something...

---

A suggestion would be to layout your arrays better. You could do this:

```
$games[] = array('home' => 'Giants', 'away' => 'Saints', 'date' => '2012-02-21')
```

and it would allow you to manipulate the array much easier.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do... match home and away teams based upon the index of the array. I've entered them all into the DB now. But, I'm not quite sure how to approach solving this error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I'm going to have a guess and say that you're trying to create match-ups (home Vs away) and store them in an array? And you're doing this by creating two separate arrays and organizing them by the same index? If that's the case, this would be a better solution:

```
<?php
$games = array(

  array('home' => 'Giants', 'away' => 'Saints', 'date' => '2012-02-21'),
  array('home' => 'Raiders', 'away' => 'Titans', 'date' => '2012-02-27')

);

foreach($games as $key => $game){
    echo $game['home'] . " vs ". $game['away']. " on " . $game['date'] . " <br /> ";
}
?>
```